# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ERROR

Tags: java, spring

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestSpringProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");

        Restaraunt restaurantObj = (Restaraunt) context.getBean("restaurantBean");

        restaurantObj.greetCustomer();
    }
}
```

run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at org.springcore.tutorials.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:8)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 8 more
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory at
```

You need [apache commons logging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) jar in your project . It is not able to resolve LogFactory in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

The commons logging class in not found by the JVM

Add commons-logging.jar to your classpath